# Formula for CSS Fix for IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

In my site I need to give support for IE7. Now everybody knows that styling things in IE7 is not an easy task. People uses conditional statement in HTML to load specific stylesheet for specific version of IE. But in my case I cannot use such conditional statement, since I am in WebCenter Portal application. Here I need to use skin. It is also a CSS file.

So I want to know is there any formula exists by which I can specify a particular css attribute's value for IE7.

Say I have a class:

```
.filterbox{
    padding:12px 0;
    margin:12px 0
}
```

Now this margin is okay for every browser except IE7 (I didn't test it in IE<7). In IE7 if I use `margin:0;` then the style would be perfect, but it then breaks in other browser.

How can I specify this margin in a same css class for both in IE7 and non-IE7?

Regards.

Comment: Can you edit the HTML file? In particular, the `<html>` element?

Comment: @CodyGray There is no such HTML file. What I have is .jsff, .jspx file and the conditional statement will not work here. I have only control on the css file.

Comment: @TapasBose Tell the developer/whoever to insert the conditional comments for you. For a better world.

Comment: @bažmegakapa I am the developer for both forntend and backend.

Comment: @TapasBose Then insert those conditional comments :). Hacks will kill you in the long run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Only use this hack if you really can't use [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html)!** They are the best solution for solving IE problems. Hacks like this will quickly mess up your CSS and also make it invalid.

So, here is a hack that targets IE7 (of course this comes after your normal definition):

```
html>body #filterbox {
*margin: 0;
}
```

from [CSS hacks – Targetting IE7 on Thought-After](http://www.thought-after.com/2006/11/css-hacks-targetting-ie7/)

Answer (score 0):

you can solve it if you seperate the style sheets for IE7 and other browser:

```
/* other browsers */
.filterbox{
padding:12px 0;
margin:12px 0
}
/* IE 7 */
*:first-child+html .filterbox
{
 padding:12px 0;
 margin:0;
}
```

Attention! You have to define the styles for Ie 7 at last, because the browser will overwrite the first definitions. The others will ignore the last ones.